# Variable access from JavaScript inherited methods

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, scope

I am studying the accessibility to variables from methods inherited from a parent to a child object.

The inheritance is performed associating an instance of the parent to the prototype of the child's constructor:

```
Function.prototype.extend = function(child) {
    var prototype = new this;

    child.prototype = prototype;
    return child;
};
```

So I define a parent class:

```
var Parent = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.init = function() {
        self.name = 'Abram';
    };
    this.getName = function() {
        alert('self.name = ' + self.name);
    };
    this.init();
};
```

and a child class:

```
var Baby = Parent.extend(function(name) {
    var self = this;

    this.init = function() {
        self.name = name;
    };
    this.init();
});

// instantiate a child object:
var baby = new Baby('Jimmy');

// call the inherited method:
baby.getName(); // undefined!
```

The method `getName` is correctly inherited, but it has no access to the `self.name` member.
How come, if it is available in the scope of the child class instance?

Checking the body of the method with `alert(baby.getName)` I get:

```
function () {
    alert("self.name = " + self.name);
}
```

which is exactly what I expected.
But why it does not resolve the `self` variable locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable "self" in the parent "getName()" function refers to the **parent** instance.  The "init" function in the child sets the name on that object, not the prototype object.

Thus:

1. `var baby = new Baby("Jimmy");` results in an object with a "name" property set to the string "Jimmy"
2. `baby.getName();` calls the function on the prototype object, since there's no "getName" property on the "baby" object. Inside that function, a reference is made to the variable "self", which refers to that prototype object — **not** to the object "baby".  There's no "name" property set on the prototype object.

See what happens if you change the `.getName()` function in the prototype to use `this.name` instead of `self.name`.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, I already tried changing the self.name into this.name and it works (at that level, which is not yet a closure), but locally named members is exactly the benefit I would like to avail myself of for an effective code reuse, for example to munge them in nested functions scope.

Comment: Well the problem is that the binding of "self" in your "Parent" function will always be to the original object instance; it's "stuck" there because of the closure.